# Uncertainty of `max` and `argmax` of values with uncertainty

Tags: error-propagation

Given a sequence $y = [y_1 \pm \Delta y_1, y_2 \pm \Delta y_2, ..., y_N \pm \Delta y_N]$, how can you compute the maximum of $y$ with its associated uncertainty, and the value of the index $i$ at which the maximum happens and its associated uncertainty?

In other words, how can you compute `max` and `argmax` values and uncertainties?

For example, in this case, it's not clear where the maximum occurs and also it's not clear the maximum value.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've decided to use a Monte-Carlo approach to solve that problem. This is, using the mean and the uncertainty values in $y$, generate $M$ experiments of the form $\tilde{y}^i = [\tilde{y}_1, ..., \tilde{y}_N]$. Then, compute the `max` and `argmax` for each experiment $\tilde{y}^i$, and finally report the average and standard deviation of the $N$ `max` and `argmax` values.

Comment: This probably is the only practical method for such a problem.  It is otherwise known as a *parametric bootstrap.*  The implicit issue, well worth analyzing, concerns how sensitive the answer is to the assumed error distributions.  Upon discovering that it can be very sensitive, many people might find a Bayesian approach to be appealing.  Another approach is to fit a suitable regression model to the data, assuming some underlying theory (or body of experience) suggests a definite model form.